# How to access safe area size in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I want to manually set the frame height of a view in SwiftUI to the size of the safe area of the screen. It's easy to get the bounds of the screen (`UIScreen.main.bounds`), but I can't find a way to access the size of the safe area.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

You can use a `GeometryReader` to access the safe area.
See: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/geometryreader.

```swift
struct ContentView : View {
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            VStack {
                Spacer()
                Color.red
                    .frame(
                        width: geometry.size.width,
                        height: geometry.safeAreaInsets.top,
                        alignment: .center
                )
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: ContentMode.fit)
            }
        }
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.bottom)
    }
}
```

But FYI: The safe area is not a size. It is an `EdgeInsets`.

Comment: This doesn't work if you use .ignoresSafeArea on a parent view.

Answer (score 49):

If you use `edgesIgnoringSafeArea` on an parentView and you want to access the device `UISafeAreaInsets` you can do the following:

**Code**

```swift
private struct SafeAreaInsetsKey: EnvironmentKey {
    static var defaultValue: EdgeInsets {
        (UIApplication.shared.windows.first(where: { $0.isKeyWindow })?.safeAreaInsets ?? .zero).insets
    }
}

extension EnvironmentValues {
    
    var safeAreaInsets: EdgeInsets {
        self[SafeAreaInsetsKey.self]
    }
}

private extension UIEdgeInsets {
    
    var insets: EdgeInsets {
        EdgeInsets(top: top, leading: left, bottom: bottom, trailing: right)
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```swift
struct MyView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.safeAreaInsets) private var safeAreaInsets
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Ciao")
            .padding(safeAreaInsets)
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not safe to assume windows[0] will return a UIWindow. As per info from this blog by Padam Thapan (https://padamthapa.com/blog/how-to-get-deprecated-keywindow-in-swift/), the first element in this array may become a UITextEffectsWindow when keypad is present on-screen. I feel like the better solution would be to wrap a reference to keyWindow in a struct and put it into Environment. This will allow us to access the above extension just as conveniently.

Comment: @Shengchalover Thanks for the feedback, I updated my answer. I decided to don't catch the reference to keyWindow because we don't know if it will change.

Comment: This code doesn't compile, you should use: static var defaultValue: EdgeInsets {
        UIApplication.shared.windows.first(where: { $0.isKeyWindow })?.safeAreaInsets.insets ?? EdgeInsets()
    }

Comment: @FarouK Now should be ok

Comment: Using this to center the View in landscape because of the home indicator, the offset of "y" should only be applied if the orientation is in landscape, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 49):

UIApplication.shared.windows is deprecated, you can now use connectedScenes:

```
import SwiftUI

extension UIApplication {
    var keyWindow: UIWindow? {
        connectedScenes
            .compactMap {
                $0 as? UIWindowScene
            }
            .flatMap {
                $0.windows
            }
            .first {
                $0.isKeyWindow
            }
    }
}

private struct SafeAreaInsetsKey: EnvironmentKey {
    static var defaultValue: EdgeInsets {
        UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.safeAreaInsets.swiftUiInsets ?? EdgeInsets()
    }
}

extension EnvironmentValues {
    var safeAreaInsets: EdgeInsets {
        self[SafeAreaInsetsKey.self]
    }
}

private extension UIEdgeInsets {
    var swiftUiInsets: EdgeInsets {
        EdgeInsets(top: top, leading: left, bottom: bottom, trailing: right)
    }
}
```

And then use Environment property in your View to get safe area insets:

```
@Environment(\.safeAreaInsets) private var safeAreaInsets
```

Comment: Is this dynamic, so does that get updated?

Comment: I seem to get a few errors when using this: `'EdgeInsets' is ambiguous for type lookup in this context` and `Type 'SafeAreaInsetsKey' does not conform to protocol 'EnvironmentKey'`. Anyone know if there's an answer that works now?

Comment: @MichaelGofron on which iOS version? I guess you probably have something else in your code causing ambiguity?

Comment: This work xcode15 IOS17?

Answer (score 15):

Not sure why the accepted answer uses top inset for a view placed under the bottom one - these are not the same.
Also if you correct this "typo", you'll see that `edgesIgnoringSafeArea` called on a `GeometryReader` zeros the corresponding value. Looks like it wasn't the case back on iOS 13, but now it is, so you need to call `edgesIgnoringSafeArea` on a `GeometryReader` child instead, and this code still works as expected on iOS 13:

```
GeometryReader { geometry in
    VStack {
        Spacer()
        Color.red
            .frame(
                width: geometry.size.width,
                height: geometry.safeAreaInsets.bottom,
                alignment: .center
            )
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: ContentMode.fit)
    }
    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.bottom)
}
```

Comment: I think you're missing a word in "... a `GeometryReader` zeros corresponding value"? In any case I worked it out; does SwiftUI have a "no-op" container for situations like this or do you just use a `VStack` even if you don't technically need one?

Comment: @RobertAtkins I'm not sure what word I might have missed here? I meant to say that if you disable `edgesIgnoringSafeArea` outside `GeometryReader`, you cannot get `geometry.safeAreaInsets` inside (the values will be zero). Using `geometry` we can get the dimensions we need, but to put the view in the right place I use `VStack`: `Spacer` takes all the remaining space and pushes my view down.

Comment: “… zeroes _the_ corresponding value” maybe? And yeah, I know a spacer will push things out of whack but I find it weird to use a `VStack` with only one thing in it. That’s not really germane to the original question though.

Comment: @RobertAtkins now I get it, thanks, I'm not a native speaker, so I make mistakes like that. It depends on the problem you need to solve, but in general it is not a bad practice to use `VStack` in this way. Drawing a view like this will not be a high-load operation. You can set the alignment of a parent view, but if you want different alignments for different children, you can use this method.

Answer (score 9):

You can also create a custom `EnvironmentValue` and pass the safe area insets over from an "initial `View`". This works perfectly for me!

#### Creating `EnvironmentValue`

```
private struct SafeAreaInsetsEnvironmentKey: EnvironmentKey {
    static let defaultValue: (top: CGFloat, bottom: CGFloat) = (0, 0)
}

extension EnvironmentValues {
    var safeAreaInsets: (top: CGFloat, bottom: CGFloat) {
        get { self[SafeAreaInsetsEnvironmentKey.self] }
        set { self[SafeAreaInsetsEnvironmentKey.self] = newValue }
    }
}
```

#### Setting

The idea is to do this before any potential `View` parent uses `.edgesIgnoringSafeArea`, this is required for it to work. For instance:

```
@main
struct YourApp: App {
    @State private var safeAreaInsets: (top: CGFloat, bottom: CGFloat) = (0, 0)
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ZStack {
                GeometryReader { proxy in
                    Color.clear.onAppear {
                        safeAreaInsets = (proxy.safeAreaInsets.top, proxy.safeAreaInsets.bottom)
                    }
                }
                
                ContentView()
                    .environment(\.safeAreaInsets, safeAreaInsets)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### Usage

```
struct SomeChildView: View {
    @Environment(\.safeAreaInsets) var safeAreaInsets

    ...
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work on iOS 17.

Answer (score 3):

```
extension UIScreen {
    static var topSafeArea: CGFloat {
        let keyWindow = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes
            .filter({$0.activationState == .foregroundActive})
            .map({$0 as? UIWindowScene})
            .compactMap({$0})
            .first?.windows
            .filter({$0.isKeyWindow}).first
        
        return (keyWindow?.safeAreaInsets.top) ?? 0
    } 
}
```

Usage:

```
UIScreen.topSafeArea
```

Answer (score 0):

I adapt for XCode15 IOS17

```swift
extension UIApplication {
    static var keyWindow: UIWindow? {
        UIApplication.shared
            .connectedScenes.lazy
            .compactMap { $0.activationState == .foregroundActive ? ($0 as? UIWindowScene) : nil }
            .first(where: { $0.keyWindow != nil })?
            .keyWindow
    }
}

private struct SafeAreaInsetsKey: EnvironmentKey {
    static var defaultValue: EdgeInsets {
        UIApplication.keyWindow?.safeAreaInsets.swiftUiInsets ?? EdgeInsets()
    }
}

extension EnvironmentValues {
    var safeAreaInsets: EdgeInsets {
        self[SafeAreaInsetsKey.self]
    }
}

private extension UIEdgeInsets {
    var swiftUiInsets: EdgeInsets {
        EdgeInsets(top: top, leading: left, bottom: bottom, trailing: right)
    }
}
```

Usage

```swift
struct ContentView: View {

    @Environment(\.safeAreaInsets) private var safeAreaInsets

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.blue
            Text("Hello world").foregroundColor(.white)
            .padding(safeAreaInsets)
        }
    }
}
```

Extract value .top safeArea
`safeAreaInsets.top`

Debug values

`let _ = print("safe area: \(safeAreaInsets)"`

You can rotate device and see all values

Comment: For iOS 17 you simply use `.safeAreaPadding`

Comment: @RaulBatista How do you get safeAreaInsets from `.safeAreaPadding`?

Comment: @DeepakSharma I mean instead of using `.padding(safeAreaInsets)` he should directly use `.safeAreaPadding` so there is no need to create extensions on iOS 17

Comment: @RaulBatista I see. I got excited to know there is a native way in iOS 17 to just read `safeAreaInsets` without such crazy workarounds but it turns out to be false.